# firefox programmatically change block pop-up windows settings

Tags: firefox

I need to access and modify `Block pop-up windows` settings for firefox from my console program. 
I have edited pref.js file but it gets overwritten when I open the browser. I tried user.js but this is permanently setting the value, which is not desirable.

Can someone provide some guidance about firefox config?

Comment: Please, describe your use case. Seems you want to disable pop-up blocking and then enable it.

Comment: i have used the user.js file for that to turn on and off block pop-up window settings. it worked.